# Why android SDK-24 needs JDK 1.8 or later to compile? What is the JDK difference in SDK-24?

Tags: java, android, sdk

When I build my project with SDK version android-24 it says requires JDK 1.8 or later to compile.

**My question is why we need JDK 1.8 version? Whats the difference/changes coming in SDK android-24?**

**Is it possible to compile project using SDK android-24 with JDK 1.7?**

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio open:
File > Project Structure > see if JDK location points to your JDK 1.8 directory.

Note: you can use compileSdkVersion 24

try this..